# Constructor php que acepta diferentes parámetros dependiendo del formulario

Tags: php, constructor

Tengo una clase "X" en PHP con 30 atributos, con un constructor que tiene la misma cantidad. Posteriormente tengo distintos formularios que capturan los datos, invoca el constructor y se crea un objeto de clase "X". Mi pregunta es, no siempre le paso al constructor los 30 atributos por parámetro, sino que dependiendo del formulario le paso 10, 15, a veces 20. Es eso posible?
Gracias!

```
public function __construct($_cod_docente=null,$_diabetes_melitus=null,$_TB=null,$_enf_mental=null,$_cardiopatias=null,$_epilepsia=null,$_geneticas=null,$_HTA=null,$_asma=null,$_hepatopatias=null,$_carcinomas=null,$_enf_endocrinas=null){   $this->cod_docente = $_cod_docente;
$this->diabetes_melitus =  $_diabetes_melitus;
$this->TB = $_TB;
$this->enf_mental = $_enf_mental;
$this->cardiopatias = $_cardiopatias;
$this->epilepsia = $_epilepsia;
$this->geneticas = $_geneticas;
$this->HTA = $_HTA;
$this->asma =$_asma;
$this->hepatopatias = $_hepatopatias;
$this->carcinomas = $_carcinomas;
$this->enf_endocrinas = $_enf_endocrinas;}
```

ese es mi constructor, entonces en algunos formularios que tengo necesito crear el objeto y pasarle solo 2 parámetros, en otro de los formularios quiero pasarle solo 3 parámetros y así consecutivamente.

Comment: Te recomiendo que coloques aquí tu código para que sea más fácil ayudarte.

Comment: Al tenerlos como `=null`, puedes en efecto omitir cualquiera de los parámetros, pero en ese caso (me parece) tendrás que pasar `null` **para guardar las correspondencias entre parámetros**. De todos modos algo hay que no cuadra en tu modelo. ¿Por qué tantos parámetros? ¿Por qué mejor no pasas un array del tipo: `array ('cod_docente' => 1, 'diabetes_melitus'=>'valor'  'otro'=> '... etc')`  luego en ese array buscas lo que hay o no hay y el código queda más limpio y fácil de mantener. Tu problema me parece que es más de diseño que de otra cosa.

Comment: La solución la encontré utilizando herencia, no se me había ocurrido! simplemente hice varias clases hija y adapte el constructor a como lo necesitaba usar en cada una de ellas. De todas maneras, gracias!